# XAML Image source with Static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a lot of images on my project that's why I created a Images resource at my solution  I referenced all those images as this:

[image]

Then I reference at my XAML as this:

```
    <Image 
        x:Name="ImgFail"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"            
        Source="{x:Static img:Imagenes.IMG_FailStamp}"/>
```

This way it throw an error on run time **Isn't a valid value for 'source'property**

But if directly reference the image as this:

```
    <Image 
        x:Name="ImgOk"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"            
        Source="/||||||||.Recursos.Imagenes;component/Resources/Ok-PNG-Pic.png"/>
```

It works.

How can i do to set Image source properly using static resources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you do

```
Source="{x:Static img:Imagenes.IMG_FailStamp}"
```

This is compiled rougly like this:

```
img.Source = Imagenes.IMG_FailStamp
```

But `Image.Source` is of type `ImageSource` and your `IMG_FailStamp` is of type `string` - this does not compile. But when you do this:

```
Source="/||||||||.Recursos.Imagenes;component/Resources/Ok-PNG-Pic.png"
```

it's different - now your string will go through the `ImageSourceConverter` and it will convert it to valid `ImageSource` (so will read your file and create source from it).

So when you use `x:Static` - you just tell directly what value to use and no converters are involved. So if you want to use `x:Static` - target property should be of type `ImageSource`.

If you still want to store paths to images in resources, do the following:

1. Open resources.resx file and change access modifier at the top from "internal" to "public". This will make `Imagenes.IMG_FailStamp` public property.
2. Bind to it like this:

   ```
   Source="{Binding Source={x:Static img:Imagenes.IMG_FailStamp}, Mode=OneTime}"
   ```

Binding will run the necessary converter and image will display fine.

Comment: Tks for your help. It means must write a converter from string to ImageSource ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez I've updated answer with a way to make it work in your scenario.